# Google currency api in android

Tags: android

I wondering if I can use Google currency API in my android application, and if it is possible; what is the URL used.

I saw this on one site : http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=all&q=100GBP=?EUR

can I use it in android application

Comment: @david99world that question is related to PHP not android

Comment: This is somewhat irrelevant, either way you're querying a web service endpoint to return a currency conversion.  The language would be agnostic.